# Add active class using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have try to add active class in active page.
I created two files. first file name is csr and csr-policy but first word are same that way display two page active same time.

```php
<ul>
  <li><a href="csr.php" <? if(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'csr')) {?> class="active" <? }?>>CSR</a></li>
  <li><a href="csr-policy.php" <? if(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'csr-policy')) {?> class="active" <? }?>>CSR Policy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? share the code

Comment: The code please..

Comment: You need some logic that'd detect the active page (based on route) and add it dynamically. We can't help you if you don't provide more details like (framework/no framework, how URLs are managed etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the easiest way to do that.
Add the code in HTML where you want to add the class:
Example:

```
    <li class="<?php if ($add_class=="") {echo "active"; }?>"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```

Here is the PHP script:

```
<?php 
$directoryURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$path = parse_url($directoryURI, PHP_URL_PATH);
$components = explode('/', $path);
$add_class = $components[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="csr.php" <?php if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])=="csr.php") {?> class="active" <?php }?>>CSR</a></li>
  <li><a href="csr-policy.php" <?php if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])=="csr-policy.php") {?> class="active" <?php }?>>CSR Policy</a></li>
</ul>
```

This might be help!

Comment: then you should upvote my answer. :) Can you please?

Answer (score 0):

You could just check it with the extension :

```
<li><a href="csr.php" <? if(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'csr.php')) {?> class="active" <? }?>>CSR</a></li>
<li><a href="csr-policy.php" <? if(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'csr-policy.php')) {?> class="active" <? }?>>CSR Policy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Also note the `strpos()` could return 0, this is not equals to false. So you have to check with a strict equality `strpos() !== false` (It seems not to be usefull in this case, but always good to know).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="csr.php" <?php if(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'csr') !== false) {?> class="active" <?php }?>>CSR</a></li>
  <li><a href="csr-policy.php" <?php if(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'csr-policy') !== false) {?> class="active" <?php }?>>CSR Policy</a></li>
</ul>
```